# can't assign convertedAccountId in lead after trigger for lead convert

Tags: trigger, lead-conversion

I am trying to create one more contact for a lead which we convert and I wrote following code for this:

```
public with sharing class LeadTriggerHandler extends TriggerHandler{

    public LeadTriggerHandler() {

    }
    protected override void afterUpdate(){
        //----get list of contacts for property manager typeÅ
        List<Contact> managerContactsToInsertList = getContactsToInsert(Trigger.new,Trigger.oldMap);
        if(managerContactsToInsertList.size() > 0){
            INSERT  managerContactsToInsertList;
        }

    }




    public List<Contact> getContactsToInsert(List<Lead> recordsList,Map<Id,Sobject> oldMap){
        List<Contact> result = New List<Contact>();
        Map<Id,Lead> oldLeadMap = (Map<Id,Lead>)oldMap;
        for(Lead record : recordsList){
            System.debug(JSON.serialize(record));
            if(record.IsConverted && !(oldLeadMap.get(record.Id).IsConverted)){
                if(String.isNotBlank(record.Oyo_Property_Manager_Name__c)){
                    result.add(New Contact(
                        Account = New Account(Id = record.convertedAccountId),
                        LastName = record.Oyo_Property_Manager_Name__c,
                        Phone = record.Oyo_Property_Manager_Number__c,
                        Email = record.Oyo_Property_Manager_Email__c
                    ));
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

In the Json which I am printing in debug, I can find convertedAccountId but new created contact don't have that Account.

Anyone have any Idea?

Thanks

Comment: SF don't natively add contact with account. you have to manually add them using lead trigger.

Comment: I am adding account in contact with trigger if you will read the code :)

Comment: Instead of **Account = New Account(Id = record.convertedAccountId)** Use **AccountId = record.convertedAccountId**

Comment: @PeeyushSachdeva please make it an answer and I will mark it correct :)

Comment: @SFDCGOD Please mark my answer as correct

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Instead of this code:**

```
Account = New Account(Id = record.convertedAccountId),
```

**Use this code:**

```
AccountId = record.convertedAccountId,
```